# Extract Background Image of an AutoShape with python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to extract all images from a PPTX file using python-pptx. I succeeded in doing this for images in shapes that have the picture style:

```
shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.PICTURE
```

but am struggling to extract images that have been added into the slide by setting them as the background image in an autoshape

```
shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.AUTO_SHAPE
```

Is there some way to extract the background image from an autoshape, or is this simply not possible through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not currently possible via the API. You'd have to go to the underlying XML to get the element that looked like `blipFill` or similar and use the `rId` it has to get to the related image.

You can inspect the XML of the shape using:

```
print(shape._sp.xml)
```

Then you can use XPath to aquire the `rId` value:

```
rId = shape._sp.xpath({xpath expr to rId attr})[0]
```

Once you have the `rId` value you can acquire a reference to the `ImagePart` using:

```
image_part = slide.part.related_part(rId)
```

Once you have the image part I expect you know what to do, getting things like `image_part.image`: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/parts/image.py#L21

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That sounds a bit more tedious than what I was hoping for, but at least there is a way to do it.